# Internet Explorer fixed positioning youtube embed issue

Tags: iframe, youtube, css-position, internet-explorer-10, fixed

Hi I am trying to create a fixed 100% width/height youtube embed, so that when you hover the mouse under the bottom of the screen a div appears. Now this works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera12, Opera15 but not in IE10. Please see the JSFiddle below to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/gQuRn/

Below is my css

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
iframe{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#bannercontainer{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background:transparent;


}

#banner{
    width:70%;
    background-color:pink;
    height:150px;
    display:none;   
    margin:auto;
}

#bannercontainer:hover #banner{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I haved fixed this now by using

    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);

instead of 

    background:transparent;

Answer (score 0):

IE10 (or even just IE) can't handle `background:transparent;`.  You should use `background:rgba(0,0,0,0)` which works the same for that to work. Although it will not be supported by older browser such as IE8.